# ssl_error_weak_server_cert_key issue in firefox

Tags: firefox, ssl, https, weblogic, ssl-certificate

I am facing the following problem when i access my local weblogic server over SSL.

My Firefox version is 39.0

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:7002. The server certificate included a public key that was too weak. (Error code: ssl_error_weak_server_cert_key) .

I red some thing related to it. It saying server is using 512 length chipper key instead of 1024 length.

Help me to get rid of this issue.

Comment: I've got reciving this error in FF 31.8 (ESR version). So it definitely looks like a problem introduced in the last security updates. Because ESR versions receive security fixes only.

Comment: I suppose I have the same problem, as I get the same error when accessing Oracle 11g db console. Google chrome writes on the same site: Connection is encrypted with obsolete cryptography and uses TLS1.0. TLS1.0 is still supported by FF, so the problem will probably be in: Server certificate is signed with weak signature key and uses a weak cryptography key.

Comment: More info: The connection is encrypted using AES_128_CBC, with SHA1 for message authentication and DHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism. So the problem is probably in the SHA1 certificate. See https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/. The SHA1 "phasing out" got probably out of control, as the schedule in the link is different.

Comment: I've filed it as a FF bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1182567. Let's see what happens :-)

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this issue occuring on local servers using self-signed certificates, for instance Webmin etc.

In such a case, you can often handle this problem by re-creating your self-signed key. Thereafter, Firefox 39 will ask the usual "confirm security exception" dialog and all is fine.

Comment: Thanks I had the same problem until I went into Webmin and recreated the certificate 2048 bits long http://i.imgur.com/BQYAx1F.png

Comment: If you have access to the server's CLI, you can do it by following this guide http://blog.rimuhosting.com/2014/11/18/webmin-sec-err-invalid-key/

Answer (score 3):

I tried to use the fix at http://frodo.looijaard.name/article/oem-database-control-security-certificate, but my emctl release on Oracle 11.1.0.6 does not support the options it details at the end.
So I fixed it by unsecuring the console.

```
emctl unsecure dbconsole
```

A somewhat poor response I agree to what Mozilla are doing, but this system is only available on an internal network.

Answer (score 0):

Also received this issue starting yesterday with FireFox version 39. There was a security update to FireFox. Couldn't immediately figure out how to reset the security prompts so I downloaded an older version and no longer receive this message.