# can't open oracle enterprise manager with firefox version 45

Tags: oracle, firefox, oracle-enterprise-manager

when my oracle enterprise manager starts it is not visible on browser and when I'm trying to attempt it through Firefox i get the this error :

> `An error occurred during a connection to oracle2017:5500. The server certificate included a public key that was too weak. Error code: SSL_ERROR_WEAK_SERVER_CERT_KEY`

please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssl\_error\_weak\_server\_cert\_key issue in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265573/ssl-error-weak-server-cert-key-issue-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

This is only a security warning. Firefox rejects sites with weak SSL security.

You must accept it as security exception. Raise a ticket to Oracle if you want better security.

Use the  <kbd>More...</kbd>  button you see or whatever link, and change your browser options for this site.
..

### edit:

- In the navigation bar:  `about:config`
- Set `security.tls.insecure_fallback_hosts = www.domain.com` (substitute the domain you're having the problem with)
- Reload the page

Comment: how can i change my browser options to attempt my oracle enterprise manager please???

Comment: see my edit for more; you may also refer to https://superuser.com/questions/826232/how-to-bypass-the-secure-connection-failed-warning-in-firefox-33

Comment: This is a better answer than any in the thread you suggested as a duplicate